# How to access smarty variable in css URL attribute?

Tags: php, css, variables, smarty, smarty2

I've used following line in my code of CSS into smarty template file :

```
background: url('{$site_url}/new_logo.jpg) no-repeat;
```

But I'm not able to locate this image. I checked in firebug console as well as in browser. Image not found message is showing.

The `{$site_url}` variable actually contains the path but I'm not able to access it. Can someone please help me in accessing this variable in above code?

Even I tried it with enclosing the above entire path into double quotes instead of single quotes, tried with removing the quotes but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to compile css than you have to create a new file where compiled css will be placed and than attach that css in your website. you can create css.tpl and compile and create style.css where all compiled code will be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss ending quote in this declaration. It should be:

```
background: url('{$site_url}/new_logo.jpg') no-repeat;
```

If it doesn't work look at your page source and make sure the image exist in this location or change value of your `$site_url` variable.

Answer (score 0):

try instead of "{$site_url}", put in your websites url, example:

> background: url('http://www.yourwebsite.com/user_ui_files/img/new_logo.jpg) no-repeat;

If the image dosen't show now, means that the {$site_url} string contains the website's url, where you got the template, and not your url.

Remeber when changing in template files, always upload with filezilla, and try in incognito, or a different browser!!

Templates normally have JavaScript files that cache all the JavaScript and CSS.

Hope it helps!